# How do I run a mocha test only after the prior asynchronous test has passed?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

Using the mocha javascript testing framework, I want to be able to have several tests (all asynchronous) only execute after the previously defined test has passed.

I don't want to have to nest these tests within each other.

```
describe("BBController", function() {
    it("should save", function(done) {});
    it("should delete", function(done) {});
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `--bail` option. Make sure you are using at least mocha 0.14.0. (I've tried it with older versions without success.)

First, there's nothing you need to do for mocha to run a test only after the previous one has finished. That's how mocha works by default. Save this to `test.js`:

```
describe("test", function () {
    this.timeout(5 * 1000); // Tests time out in 5 seconds.

    it("first", function (done) {
        console.log("first: do nothing");
        done();
    });

    it("second", function (done) {
        console.log("second is executing");
        // This test will take 2.5 seconds.
        setTimeout(function () {
            done();
        }, 2.5 * 1000);
    });

    it("third", function (done) {
        console.log("third is executing");
        // This test will time out.
    });

    it("fourth", function (done) {
        console.log("fourth: do nothing");
        done();
    });
});
```

Then execute it with:

```
mocha -R spec test.js
```

You will not see the fourth test start until:

1. The first and second tests are finished.
2. The third tests has timed out.

Now, run it with:

```
mocha -R spec --bail test.js
```

Mocha will stop as soon as test 3 fails.

Answer (score -6):

if your tests are set up properly, only testing a small piece of business logic then you can run your tests asynchronously but they should not hold up other tests. the way to get a test to complete is to do the following:

```
describe("BBController", function() {
    it("should save", function(done) {
       // handle logic
       // handle assertion or other test
       done(); //let mocha know test is complete - results are added to test list
    });
    it("should delete", function(done) {
       // handle logic
       // handle assertion or other test
       done(); //let mocha know test is complete - results are added to test list
    });
});
```

again, no test should need to wait for another test to run to pass, if you have this issue then you should look at ways to impove your dependency injection or prep your tests with a before method

Comment: You're just saying the tests shouldn't be structured as I asked, which doesn't answer the question. Also, your code just calls done() which is not relevant to setting any sort of dependency as I was asking. I assume what you really want to say is that mocha doesn't support this form of dependency.

Comment: Does not answer question in any way... As Tim said. Done is not relevant to this question.

Comment: the answer states that the tests are not set up correctly, no test should ever depend on any other test running to be valid. any setup need to run a test should be run in a before block, as a matter of fact, it is a good practice to run your tests in random order to ensure you don't have test dependencies like that

Comment: @kkemple I am new to testing and have similar problem as topic starter: I have test "login" which logins on server and performs checks if server responds correctly and further tests "plant tree", "dig garden", ... which are server requests to check if server properly responds (also checking server's state with "getters"). Not sure if I have any options on running such tests independently ... hmm.

Comment: You do have the option, it just depends on how you structure those tests

      describe 'authenticated users can'
        beforeEach -> log in user
        afterEach -> log user out
        test 'plant tree'
        test 'dig garden'